# ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types(LoaderExceptions)

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my application where I load a list of assemblies (Assembly.LoadFrom) from a path (\ \ RemoteServerDir ...) and when I try to retrieve all types of each assemblies i get errors when calling assembly.GetTypes () method.

The message that i have is "ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the Requested types (LoaderExceptions)".

Does someone has an idea to solve this?
For information, this application is running in distributed mode who i have this probleme but  in local mode it works well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably it is has to do with different permission level when you loading remote assemplies

Please try replacing Assembly.LoadFrom to **Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom** available in C# 4.0 [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.unsafeloadfrom.aspx) which will bypass security checks

Old way is to add configuration section

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

which will load assembly with full trust

Comment: ok i'm trying this.,i'm working with the framework 3.5 and the Assembly.LoadFrom works well but the getTypes failed.

Comment: Have you added config section?